# Calling class method from another method kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a problem with calling a class method from another class in Kivy. I have two screens, navigating between them worked (with self.manager.current = name), but now when I try calling this class method from another class, it gives me this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current'
I guess that when I call the method with CLASS().METHOD() i make the self.manager.current, in the class where is the method, refer to this call and that causes the error. Like uninitializes or something. I could be wrong.
You got some tips and explanations?
Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Post a minimal runnable example. 2) `CLASS().METHOD()` is almost certainly wrong, you likely want to access some method of an _existing_ class instance, not a new one you just made.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that too, I basically run init twice. But I don't know how to access the method of an existing class instance. Could you help?

Comment: http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/

Comment: Thanks! That helps a little bit, but I have now a different problem. I can't call the method with App.get_running_app().METHOD, because the ObjectProperty is in a different class, and I can't define the ObjectProperty in my App class because the method is in different class. A little more help? Please.